# Pickle problem writing to file

Tags: python, pickle

I have a problem writing a file with Pickle in Python

Here is my code:

```
test = "TEST"
f1 = open(path+filename, "wb", 0)
pickle.dump(test,f1,0)
f1.close()
return
```

This gives me the output in the .txt file as `VTESTp0.` I'm not sure why this is? 
Shouldn't it just have been saved as `TEST`?

I'm very new to `pickle` and I didn't even know it existed until today so sorry if I'm asking a silly question.

Comment: The short answer is no.

Pickle is not used to produce output files to be read directly but to be read again by pickle.

The point is to save data when you close a program for instance, then pickle it "up" to load it again.

Look at this: http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, pickle does not write strings just as strings. Pickle is a *serialization* protocol, it turns objects into strings of bytes so that you can later recreate them. The actual format depends on which version of the protocol you use, but you should really treat pickle data as an opaque type.

If you want to write the string `"TEST"` to the file, just write the string itself. Don't bother with pickle.

Comment: Well actually im trying to save an array of tuples (int, String).
I just put the 'TEST' in there to see if it was working. I'm doing this for a high score system in blender. 
How would I go about saving this?

Comment: What do you expect the file to contain, then? If you want something *human-readable*, perhaps you want to use a format like JSON instead. Pickle does not produce readable strings, as such.

Comment: When first posting this question I had no idea pickle saved it in un-readable formats. Thats okay though, it's not important - I was just confused.

How would i go about saving/loading:
`scores=[(1489,"Sean"), (2850,"Bob")]`

I can save easily using the `file.write` methods but not sure how to read it back in. Is pickle still the best option? 
Note that now I realise I dont have to be able to read the saved txt file myself.

Comment: If you want to use pickle you use `pickle.load` or `pickle.loads` to read it back. The `json` module does the same thing for JSON, which will be more readable and less fragile than pickle.

Answer (score 0):

Think of pickling as saving *binary data* to disk. This is interesting if you have data structures in your program like a big dict or array, which took some time to create. You can save them to a file with pickle and read them in with pickle the next time your program runs, thus saving you the time it took to build the data structure. The downside is that other, non-Python programs will not be able to understand the pickle files.

As pickle is quite versatile you can of course also write simple text strings to a pickle file. But if you want to process them further, e.g. in a text editor or by another program, you need to store them verbatim, as Thomas Wouters suggests:

```
test = "TEST"
f1 = open(path+filename, "wb", 0)
f1.write(test)
f1.close()
return
```